# NaN and +-INF in floating point number system following IEEE754

Tags: language-agnostic, system, ieee-754, floating

In the standard, representation of **NaN** and **INF** is like this:

For **NaN**: exponent = emax+1 & mantissa != 0;

For **INF**: exponent = emax+1 & mantissa = 0;

Their are many ways and calculations resulting these two value.

But what ACTUALLY is **NaN(INF)**?

And **HOW** does the system "decide" or "judge" to store value as these one(two)?

Here may be a case seeming to be odd to me:

**a = b = 1*2(emax)**;

**then calculating c = a+b, the actual result is 1*2^(emax+1)**;

Now, c is not an available FP value according to the standard;

then how does the system store c in device?

Is it **NaN**?

If yes, how can this be even reasonable?

I mean, 1*2^(emax+1) IS(Should be) a Number...in a common sense...?

If this is the case, then how ACTUALLY does the standard think what a NaN is?

If not, then how do we deal with this???

I'm considering one like this:

let eM = emax+1;

then 1d.d...d * 2^(eM-1) = 1d.d...d * 2^(emax)

with 1d.d...d having legal number of digits by the system.

This is actually a way like that dealing with denormalized number.

---

The thing here is this:

Is the judgement ***posterior* or *prior*** to the completion of calculation?

If it's the former, the above may be a problem or not?

On the other hand, then the task seems undonable...

Is there anyone ever thinking about this issue?

Thx for considering it!!

Note: things for +-INF are also presented.

Comment: All your questions are answered in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Exception_handling . Don't spend pages pondering one alternative and then the other. It makes for a uselessly long question that would be unrewarding to answer completely.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Exception_handling):

The five possible exceptions are:

- **Invalid operation** (e.g., square root of a negative number) (**returns qNaN** by default).
- **Division by zero** (an operation on finite operands gives an exact **infinite result**, e.g., 1/0 or log(0)) (returns ±infinity by default).
- **Overflow** (a result is too large to be represented correctly) (**returns ±infinity** by default (for round-to-nearest mode)).
- **Underflow** (a result is very small (outside the normal range) and is inexact) (**returns a denormalized value** by default).
- ...